# Laravel5 Eloquent select from multiple table with where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How to do this query in Laravel Eloquent?

```
SELECT * FROM `ftm_users`, `ftm_students`, `ftm_user_verification` WHERE `ftm_users`.`user_group` = 3 AND `ftm_user_verification`.`verification_status` = 1 AND `ftm_users`.`uid` = `ftm_students`.`uid` AND `ftm_users`.`uid` = `ftm_user_verification`.`uid`
```

I already set the relationship in Model and I have tried with this

```
$userStudent = User::where('user_group', '=', 3)->with(array('userVerification' => function($query) {
        $query->where('verification_status', '=', 1);
    }, 'student', 'studentParents'))->simplePaginate(20);
```

but the query is using separated select statement to get data from different table.

Thanks.

Comment: The query you are showing will not work, you will have to use a join to filter on another table.

Comment: Can you please be more specific in your question? Your first `mysql` statement shows an attempt at doing joins. The second code is an attempt at selecting filtered records.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you defined the relationships between `ftm_users` and `ftm_user_verification`, you can use the `whereHas` method to filter related models

```
$userStudent = User::where('user_group', '=', 3)->whereHas('userVerification', function ($query) {
    $query->where('verification_status', '=', 1);
})->get();
```

Check [Querying Relationship Existence](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) in the docs